# Custom ClassLoader with resource loading

Tags: java, classloader

I'm writing a plugin loader -- it loads jars that are not on the classpath. I wrote a simple custom ClassLoader that takes a JarFile in its constructor and looks in the JarFile for the named class. This loader simply overrides the `findClass()` method of ClassLoader, and works fine.

Then I determined that I also needed to be able to get resources from the plugin jar. So I overrode `findResource()`. This had the unexpected result of causing the base plugin class to not be able to find other classes in the jar: I get NoClassDefFoundErrors!

In other words, if I have plugin.jar that contains MyPlugin and MyPluginComponent:

- if I do not override `findResource()`, then I can load the jar, create an instance of MyPlugin, and that in turn can create a MyPluginComponent. However I cannot find resources that are bundled in the jar.
- if I do override `findResource()`, then I can load the jar, create an instance of MyPlugin, *but* if MyPlugin attempts to create a MyPluginComponent, I get a NoClassDefFoundError.

This suggests that somehow the implementation of findResource() is unable to find class files -- but it's not even getting called (per my logging), so I don't see how that could be the case. How does this interaction work out, and how do I fix it?

I tried to write a small self-contained example, and ran into difficulty manually generating a jar file that wouldn't produce "incompatible magic number" errors. Hopefully whatever I'm doing wrong will be evident from the class loader alone. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thank you for your time.

```
import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.lang.ClassLoader;

import java.net.URL;

import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

/**
 * Custom class loader for loading plugin classes. Adapted from
 * http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-write-custom-class-loader-to.html
 */
public static class PluginLoader extends ClassLoader {
    private JarFile jarFile_;
    public PluginLoader(JarFile jarFile) {
        super(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        jarFile_ = jarFile;
    }

    @Override
    public Class findClass(String className) {
        try {
            // Replace "." with "/" for seeking through the jar.
            String classPath = className.replace(".", "/") + ".class";
            System.out.println("Searching for " + className + " under " + classPath);
            JarEntry entry = jarFile_.getJarEntry(classPath);
            if (entry == null) {
                return null;
            }
            InputStream stream = jarFile_.getInputStream(entry);
            String contents = CharStreams.toString(
                    new InputStreamReader(stream));
            stream.close();
            byte[] bytes = contents.getBytes();
            Class result = defineClass(className, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            return result;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e + "Unable to load jar file " + jarFile_.getName());
        }
        catch (ClassFormatError e) {
            System.out.println(e + "Unable to read class data for class " + className + " from jar " + jarFile_.getName());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected URL findResource(String name) {
        System.out.println("Asked to find resource at " + name);
        try {
            String base = new File(jarFile_.getName()).toURI().toURL().toString();
            URL result = new URL(String.format("jar:%s!/%s", base, name));
            System.out.println("Result is " + result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e + "Unable to construct URL to find " + name);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        System.out.println("Getting resource at "  +name);
        JarEntry entry = jarFile_.getJarEntry(name);
        if (entry == null) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't find resource " + name);
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return jarFile_.getInputStream(entry);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e + "Unable to load resource " + name + " from jar file " + jarFile_.getName());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are not using `URLClassLoader`? It gives you all these features.

Comment: @KDM because I didn't stumble across that option, somehow. Which is weird because I did a lot of searching on this. I'll blame it on being stupid due to having recently returned from vacation.

Comment: Note that there is also a "findResources" method. I found in my own code that "findResource" wasn't called while "findResources" was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is to just read extra JAR files extending `URLClassLoader` might be a better option.

```
public class PluginLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public PluginLoader(String jar) throws MalformedURLException {
        super(new URL[] { new File(jar).toURI().toURL() });
    }

}
```

Comment: Odd how I didn't stumble across that option. It produces similar results as my manual ClassLoader with resource loading: I can see the base plugin class, but when that class tries to refer to another class in the jar, I get a NoClassDefFoundError. The weird thing is I can see via logging that the secondary classes are loaded just fine, but I still get the error.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out: I had a static member field whose initialization involved an invalid casting operation. Consequently the class could not be instantiated. Why this shows up as NoClassDefFoundError, I don't know, but I think I can proceed now. Thanks for the assist.